# Missing required parameters for [Route: photographers.edit] [URI: posts/edit/{photographers}]

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6

I Get this error every time I create an edit button or even a button to view a particular post in my project.

Here's my route code:

```
Route::get('/posts/edit/{photographers}', 'PhotographerController@edit')
    ->name('photographers.edit');
```

Here's my edit function in the controller file :

```
public function edit(Photographer $photographer)
        {
            return view('photographers.edit', compact('photographer'));
        }
```

Here's my view button route:

```
<a href="{{route('photographers.edit', $photographer)}}">Edit</a>
```

I read a lot of previous posts on this issue but didn't really help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sometimes the dependency injection can be the cause of the error, you can use id as follows

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $photographer = Photographer::find($id);

        return view('photographers.edit', compact('photographer'));
    }
```

I also noticed in your blade file, you are passing the entire $photographer as an argument, you only need to pass the id

```
<a href="{{route('photographers.edit', $photographer->id)}}">Edit</a>
```

Comment: Naah man, Still the same error

Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException
Missing required parameters for [Route: photographers.edit] [URI: posts/edit/{photographers}]. (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/photographers/show.blade.php)

Comment: Don't pass the entire $photographer object, only pass the **id** as an argument in the blade

Comment: It did show the edit button finally, but the moment I click that edit button

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'photographers.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `photographers` where `photographers`.`id` = 13 limit 1)

This error

Comment: hope you are not using **photographers->id**, it should be **photographer->id**

Comment: <a href="{{route('photographers.edit', $photographer->photo_id)}}">Edit</a>

photo_id because that's my id name so this is my function

public function edit($photo_id)
    {
        $photographer = Photographer::find($photo_id);

        return view('photographers.edit', compact('photographer'));
    }

Comment: instead of this **$photographer = Photographer::find($photo_id);**, use this  **$photographer = Photographer::where('photo_id', $photo_id)->first();**

Comment: It worked man. But all my header elements which I imported using extents(layouts.master) are saying 404 not found in that blade file. Like my logo isn't there, search bar icon isn't there but it works on all the other files.  Weird. But it did work. I would be happy if you could solve this too

Comment: its **@extends(layouts.master)**, not **extents** and also, if you want to import other pages in one page you can use **include**, i.e **@include('photographer.others')**

Comment: Yeah, I wrote extends, Sorry it was a typo in the previous comment. Include fetched the same output. But no worries, you've helped enough man! Can't thank you enough